# Different Date Formats in R

Tags: r, date

In my R data set there is a **data$date** variable, made of two different writting : some are **dd-mmm-yy** (ex. "14-nov-17") and others are **ddMMMyyyy** (ex. "14APR2016").

Here I'm stuck. How can I get all of them to date format ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

An option would be `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` which can take multiple `Date` formats

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(v1, c("%d-%b-%y", "%d%b%Y"))
#[1] "2017-11-14 UTC" "2016-04-14 UTC"
```

---

Or with `anydate` from `anytime`.  But, applying `anydate`, check whether all the `format`s are already present with

```
library(anytime)
getFormats()
```

If some `format`s are missing, add it with `addFormats`

```
addFormats("%d-%b-%y")
```

and then apply the `anydate` on the column/vector of dates

```
anydate(v1)
#[1] "2017-11-14" "2016-04-14"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("14-nov-17", "14APR2016")
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly ! amazing package.

Comment: @CactusTown  Thank you for the comments.  You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927770/how-to-programatically-isolate-one-line-out-of-a-series-of-lines-in-ggplot/53928384#53928384)

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you want to use base R and like regular expressions:

```
data$date <- as.Date(sub('(\\d{2})(\\w{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})', '\\1-\\2-\\4', data$date),
                     format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

Comment: No, just say no.  Never ever use regexps for data parsing when suitable libraries exist.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I agree that 99% of the time (this case being one of them) that it is better to use a suitable library. Sometimes though I avoid libraries that help just one calculation if the code is being shared with people using different platforms, as package management and installation creates more dependencies and chances for things to go wrong. Would you argue that it would still be better for the sake of cleaner code?